# Swift count each array based on conditional date range

Tags: arrays, swift, date

Unsure how to bring back an array in the IF statement with an operator. I am looking to track how many runs (jogs) happen ONLY over the last 7 days in Swift. Initially I want to populate each jog array item with a date when the jog is input then I want to count all array items ONLY within the last 7 days. Then the user can see how many jogs they undertook every time they log in. Thank you in advance.

// set my model

```
struct arrayOfJogs {
    var jogTitle = ""
    var jogDate = Date()

    init(jogTitle: String, jogDate: Date) {
        self.jogTitle = jogTitle
        self.jogDate = Date()
    }
}
```

// test array with dates - all set to today

```
var jogs: [arrayOfJogs] = [arrayOfJogs(jogTitle: "Around City", jogDate: Date()) arrayOfJogs(jogTitle: "The Castle", jogDate: Date()), arrayOfJogs(jogTitle: "The kettle", jogDate: Date())]
```

// the function

```
func datesRangeToCheck() -> [jogDate] {
    let sevenDaysAgoSinceToday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -8, to: Date())!
    if arrayOfJogs.jogDate < sevenDaysAgoSinceToday {
        return [jogDate]()
    }
}
```

// retrieving the arrays back

```
`let arrayDatesToCheck = datesRangeToCheck()`
```

// counting the arrays

```
let totalCountedArrayItemsOverTheLastSevenDays = arrayDatesToCheck.count
```

Comment: Gimme a few mins and I'll throw something on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my friend. I threw together something you can dump in a playground. There's a lot of minor issues going on with your code, so I cleaned it up a little. First thing's first.

1. You don't need to put an initializer on a `struct`. You get it "for free", so your declaration will look like so:

```
// CapitalizedCamelCase for classes, structs, enums & typedefs
struct Jogs {
    // You get an initializer for "free" with a struct
    var jogTitle: String
    var jogDate: Date
}
```

Then, once you declare all your structs and dump them in an array, you'll want to use `filter`. It'll look something like this:

```
let filteredJogs = jogs.filter { $0.jogDate >= Date() }
let filteredJogCount = filteredJogs.count
```

So anyway, here's some code you can dump in a playground and play around with:

```
// CapitalizedCamelCase for classes, structs, enums & typedefs
struct Jogs {
    // You get an initializer for "free" with a struct
    var jogTitle: String
    var jogDate: Date
}

// I'm doing this b/c I'm lazy and don't wanna create the dates "by hand"
func randomDateGenerator() -> [Date] {
    var arrayOfDates: [Date] = []
    let days = Array(1...30)
    days.forEach { day in
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.month = 4
        components.day = day
        components.year = 2020

        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)! // Don't force unwrap (!) in production code
        arrayOfDates.append(newDate)
    }

    return arrayOfDates
}

let today: Date = {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.month = 4
    components.day = 30
    components.year = 2020

    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
}()

enum TimeSpan {
    case lastWeek
    case lastTwoWeeks
    case lastMonth
}

var jogNames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
let jogDates = randomDateGenerator()

var arrayOfJogs: [Jogs] = []

zip(jogNames, jogDates).forEach { title, date in
    let structToAdd = Jogs(jogTitle: title,
                           jogDate: date)
    arrayOfJogs.append(structToAdd)
}

func getJogs(for timeSpan: TimeSpan, jogs: [Jogs], today: Date) -> [Jogs] {
    var referenceDate: Date

    switch timeSpan {
    case .lastWeek:
        referenceDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: today)!
    case .lastTwoWeeks:
        referenceDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -14, to: today)!
    case .lastMonth:
        referenceDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: today)!
    }

    return jogs.filter { $0.jogDate >= referenceDate }
}

let lastSevenDays = getJogs(for: .lastWeek, jogs: arrayOfJogs, today: today)

lastSevenDays.forEach { filteredJog in
    print(filteredJog.jogDate)
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much  some niffy tricks and tips there to learn from so much appreciated 

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help. Swift is a fun language. Enjoy learning it.

Comment: One more suggestion if you're trying to "get your head" around what's going on with code is to add a test in XCTestCase class. That would enable you to put breakpoints in, which you can't do in Playgrounds.

Comment: Hi @Adrian 

The part where I am setting the current date: 
let today: Date = {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.month = 4
    components.day = 30
    components.year = 2020

    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
}()

How do I set this to be today's date without hardcoding? Thank you

Comment: `let today = Date()`

Comment: I did try that but it did not work for me. Do I need to format Date() in any way before passing it through perhaps? Thank you @Adrian

Comment: When I print the array I see this: 
[__lldb_expr_28.Jogs(jogTitle: "a", jogDate: 2020-05-01 04:00:00 +0000),  ...

Comment: I got it working, I was not bringing back the arrays properly after I changed your code. Thank you :) sorry to be a pain